# spacy fails to fetch GPU in Azure Databricks

Tags: python, nlp, databricks, spacy, named-entity-recognition

Thanks in Advance! I am trying to train my Spacy NERv model in Azure Databricks. My current python version is 3.9.5. when i execute "spacy.require_gpu()" it fails and throws a value error stating "GPU is not available". But when I import torch and check for GPU it is showing that GPU is available. Could anyone help me on the same?

Comment: I am having the same issue in my databricks environment

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and installing the items below in sequence and it worked.

1. !pip install --upgrade pip
2. !pip install spacy
3. !pip install cupy-cuda11x
4. !pip install spacy-transformers
5. !pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118
6. import spacy
7. spacy.require_gpu()#True